# Next.js router.push encodes query parameters

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to make a redirect using `router.push` to pass a query string, but when I try to pass a value in my param with special characters as a comma is encoding my URL. Is it possible to pass ',' into an URL using `router.push`?

I have tried a lot of things but I don't know how to make it work.

```
router.push({
  pathname: router.pathname,
  query: { ...router.query, pets: 'cats,dogs'},
})
```

The resulting URL will be `myurl?pets=cats%2Cdogs`, I want it to be `myurl?pets=cats,dogs`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [URL object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object) format for the path and query string will internally encode the query parameters.

To avoid this, you can pass the path and query string as a string instead.

```js
router.push(`${router.asPath}?pets=cats,dogs`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode and encode URI params. Router automatically encodes query params for you:

```js
encodeURIComponent('cats,dogs')
// "cats%2Cdogs"
```

You need to **decode** them when reading:

```js
decodeURIComponent("cats%2Cdogs")
// "cats,dogs"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The following will still be encoded by Router.push:
```router.push({
  pathname: router.pathname,
  query: { ...router.query, pets: 'cats,dogs'},
})```

Comment: I am having the same issue with next router. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: As you said router automatically encodes query params for you. If you do this, you're double encoding them. You'd want `cats,dogs` and now you get `cats%252Cdogs` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the question above,
I have deduced that there are some other query params as well except the pathname(which comes in slug). And you wish to add `pets=cats,dogs` to it.

If someone want's to get the pathname, we can use
`window.location.pathname` and the rest of the old query params can be accessed using `window.location.search`.

And to sum it all up, one can easily use

```
const subpathAndQuery = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
router.push(`${subpathAndQuery}&pets=cats,dogs`);
```

**NOTE**: if `pets=cats,dogs` is the first key-value pair of the query param. You will have to use `?` instead of `&`.